# Any ideas as to what this is?

Tags: electrical, switch

[image]

This is in a house my daughter bought and no one knows what it is for. It is a 1930's house. Has a switch on it that when you flip it a red light flickers on for a second and nothing else seems to happen. Any ideas?

Comment: Emergency off for an oil fired furnace or boiler is my bet.

Comment: You could try cycling through the breaker box in the house if you are really curious - it could help you figure out what circuit it is connected to.  Then just look at what's on that circuit.

Comment: If you have any older heat tape that was not controlled by a thermostat as my mother's was, on a water line or on the roof , it could control those items.

Comment: It does look like it has been modified, for example-that looks like a pill bottle attached to the bottom.

Comment: You should at least open it up (it looks like there are 2 screws holding the plate) and examine the inside.  That should give some clue as to what it is.

Comment: Where is it located in the house? The 70's pannelling suggests basement. And the box suggests it was added after.  How old and what type of furnace? Any crawl spaces?